# Is there a way to protect the master node from autoscalling?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am initializing a kubernetes cluster with `Terraform`, I created an `aws_autoscaling_group` for autoscaling, but I want to protect the master node from autoscaling. I haven't found a setting in the official documentation that could solve my problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you using EKS?

Comment: @initanmol no I am using just EC2

Comment: Provision K8S master on an independent EC2 node and keep K8S workers nodes in an autoscaling group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Terraform `aws_autoscaling_group`  just set `min_size`, `max_size` and `desired_capacity` all to the same value. If you have 3 master nodes set all of them to 3. This will effectively disable autoscaling, but will always keep you cluster with 3 master nodes.